write a double arrow
I want to write the equilibrium equation of ethanoic acid in water using the chemmacro package but I can't find a suitable command.
The only trick I found is to create the "reactive" part with \ch{CH3COOH + H2O} then add the double arrow $\rightlefthaproons$ then the products \ch{CH3COO- + H2O}.
Is there a way to add the double arrow directly in the \ch command to only have one?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Simply use <=>:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{CH3COOH + H2O <=> CH3COO- + H3O+}

\end{document}


